# Can't sudo dpkg --configure -a nvidia drives Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, dpkg

With Nvidia drivers installed my Ubuntu 20.04 boots to a black screen with a cursor in the bottom right corner. The system is totally unresponsive no keyboard shortcuts work and a power reset is needed to reboot.

I can boot into grub with ESC button recovery mode for the current kernel totally unresponsive require a power reset to get back to grub.

Previous kernel recovery mode response to commands dpkg function crashes the system and back to the black screen with a cursor.

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install

Will not work error message says to enter the command " sudo dpkg --configure -a " which crashes the system brings me back to the black screen and cursor.

I am stuck on Nvidia driver 460.39 can't get rid of it can't update, upgrade, install anything stuck an " sudo dpkg --configure -a " crash > boot to grub > old kernel recovery mode > unable to do anything unless I " sudo dpkg --configure -a " crash > boot grub > repeat

Googled and search for two days none of the videos or forum post guidance working.

System Info:

Memory 15.6 Gib

Intel i7-4790k CPU @ 4.00 GHZ x 8

GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

Disk 3.5 TB

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

64-bit

Gnome Ver. 3.36.8

windowing system x11

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!
CHERNO

Comment: same on 20.04.3